# Can't access the SQLite database with MAMP and PHP

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I have been learning how to program websites lately and the time has come for me to add a database.  I have in fact already successfully created a MySQL database and interacted with it with PHP.

My problem is I can't seem to access a SQLite database file with it.  I am using MAMP to host locally for now.  Here is a snippet of the code I am using to access the db and find and print out a value stored on it.

```
<?php
        $dbhandle = sqlite_open('/Applications/MAMP/db/sqlite/Users');

        if ($dbhandle == false) die ('Unable to open database');

        $dbquery = "SELECT * FROM usernames WHERE username=trevor";
        $dbresult = sqlite_query($dbhandle, $dbquery);

        echo sqlite_fetch_single($dbresult);
        sqlite_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: Do you get into the `die` part ? Or get an error later ?

Comment: no, it returns true.  I checked that by echoing something in an else statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have access to the database *(your code doesn't `die`)*, I'd say there's got to be an error later ;-)

Looking at your SQL query, I see this :

```
SELECT * FROM usernames WHERE username=trevor
```

Are you sure you don't need to put quotes arround that string ?

Like this :

```
SELECT * FROM usernames WHERE username='trevor'
```

Also, notice that [`sqlite_fetch_single`][1] will only fetch the first row of your data -- which means you might need to use [`sqlite_fetch_array`][2] or [`sqlite_fetch_object`][3] if you want to access all the fields of your resulset.